# How to Add White Border to colored Geom_Point

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am reading https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html. Exercise 3.6.1. asks to create this

[image]

I tried `fill = drv`

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "white", fill = drv, size = 5, stroke = 5)
```

and `fill = factor(drv)`

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, colour = "white", fill = factor(drv), size = 5, stroke = 5)
```

And get error

> object 'drv' not found

Comment: pass the fill in the `aes` like `geom_point(aes(fill = drv), color = "white, ...`

Comment: Thanks man @dc37

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

they are two geom_points merged

```
ggplot(data = mpg, mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) +
  geom_point(size = 4, colour= "white", stroke = 6)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(color = drv), size = 5)
```